# How to read a particular value from the json.stringify: ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

From the post i have got a res as

```
.subscribe( res => {
    let result = JSON.stringify(res);
    alert(result)
})
```

& as the response of `alert(result)` I’m getting

```
{"access_token": "hjhdshJHUHYI67HUjhhk98BJ_BJHBBHbnbhbhbjh_jmnhghmghgfffgxcgfcf98hujh",
 "expires_in":"518399"}
```

Here I want to read the `access_token` value & save it in a variable how Can I do it?

Comment: Why would you like to stringify it?

Comment: `res.access_token` should do it. I understand now what you''ve been doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to stringify, just access it as `res.access_token`

```
.subscribe((res:any) => {
  let result = res.access_token;
  alert(result)
})
```

Comment: Property 'access_token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

Just access that property of the object with the usual syntax.

```
.subscribe( res => {
    let the_variable = res['access_token']; //or `result.access_token`
})
```

Comment: @user184994 My bad, I skimmed over it thinking it was `JSON.parse`!

Answer (score 0):

```
.subscribe( res => {
    alert(res.access_token)
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
.subscribe( res => {
     alert(res.access_token)
 })
```

If you are unable to solve your problem by following solution..

There is no need to stringify the result.
Please try following..

```
.subscribe( res => {
    alert(res['access_token']);
})
```